# Kafka Config not loading bootstrap server address

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am working on a microservice architecture using Spring boot. One of my application act as a Kafka producer to write logs on a Kafka topic. My producer config is as follow:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
@Value("${kafka.address:X.X.X.X:9092}")
private String bootstrapAddress;
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, KafkaTopicMessage> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();

    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringOrBytesSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}


@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaTopicMessage> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
}
```

Also, my topic config is :

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

@Value("${kafka.address:X.X.X.X:9092}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic logTopic() {
    return new NewTopic("log-topic", 1, (short) 1);
}
}
```

And Another application is consuming this topic. My consumer Config is like below:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaTopicMessage> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaTopicMessage> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, KafkaTopicMessage> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "X.X.X.X:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "log");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

}
```

I have also included the configuration application.yml file. like this:

```
kafka:
address: X.X.X.X:9092

spring:
    kafka:
        consumer:
            bootstrap-servers: ${kafka.address}
            group-id: log
            auto-offset-reset: earliest
            key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        properties:
            spring:
                json:
                    trusted:
                        packages: '*'
    producer:
        bootstrap-servers: ${kafka.address}
        key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

The problem is that even though I'm giving my server addresses explicitly it is trying to connect to `127.0.0.1:9092`. Can anybody help me with this problem? why it is not reading my config and why it's going to have a default config?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you are using spring-boot, auto-configuration should be applied by default, and customized through `application.properties` according to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka)

Comment: @samabcde I have used that too. but it's not working too and it's really weird.

Comment: Please also include your `application.properties` to see if there is anything wrong.

Comment: @samabcde I have included my application.yml file.

Comment: Can you try to add this to the yml?
`spring: kafka: bootstrap-servers: X.X.X.X:9092`

Comment: Since you are wiring up your own producer and consumer factories, the application.yml `spring.kafka.*` properties are not used at all. Why don't you just use the Boot auto-configured factories? That said, it's not clear why your `@Value` is not being used - have you run it in a debugger?